# How could I programmatically add google sheet conditional formatting rules to show color ranges for every second column?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a spreadsheet with many rows containing timing data.  The format is like

| A total | B timing | C total2 | D timing2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2353 | 0.4 | 4264 | 0.5 |
| 43253 | 0.8 | 32443 | 0.1 |

etc
The columns go up to RR, so I can't manually do this well.  I only want to put the highly range formatting on every 2nd column (the timing columns)

Is there a way to script this?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this.

It's really three main parts:

1. an algo to generate the alphabetic array
2. some google sheet handlers
3. the conditional Rules API, to push the new rules onto the stack of existing rules in the sheet.

```js
    function myFunction() {
    
      function base26ToAlphabet() {
        // const alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
        const alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
        const sequenceLength = 300;
        let count = 2;
        let result = [];
    
        for (let i = 0; i < sequenceLength; i++) {
          let base26Number = '';
          let dividend = count - 1;
    
          while (dividend >= 0) {
            const remainder = dividend % 26;
            base26Number = alphabet[remainder] + base26Number;
            dividend = Math.floor(dividend / 26) - 1;
          }
    
          result.push(base26Number);
          count += 2;
        }
    
        return result;
      }
    
      // Example usage:
      const numbersInAlphabet = base26ToAlphabet();
      // console.log(numbersInAlphabet);
    
    
    
      numbersInAlphabet.forEach((columnCode) => {
        var rangeCodes = columnCode+':'+columnCode;
        
        var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
        spreadsheet.getRange(rangeCodes).activate(); // 'IZ:IZ'
        
        var conditionalFormatRules = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getConditionalFormatRules();
        
        conditionalFormatRules.push(SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
          .setRanges([spreadsheet.getRange(rangeCodes)])
          .setGradientMinpoint('#57BB8A')
          .setGradientMidpointWithValue('#FFD666', SpreadsheetApp.InterpolationType.PERCENTILE, '50')
          .setGradientMaxpoint('#E67C73')
          .build());
        spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setConditionalFormatRules(conditionalFormatRules);
      });
      
    };
```